# How to construct cache with ArrayList<Long> as values using Ehcache 3?

Tags: java, arraylist, ehcache

This code compiles fine.  However, if I want to use `ArrayList<Long>` instead of `Long[]` as my value, I run into a little trouble:
Replacing `Long[].class` with `ArrayList<Long>.class` does not work.  I assume this is because the templated Object is dynamically compiled and does not have an existing .class file.  What should I be using instead?

```
public class junky{
    PersistentCacheManager myStore;
    String filename;
    Cache<Long, Long[]> myCache;

    public junky(String filename){
        this.filename = filename;
        myStore = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder()
            .with(CacheManagerBuilder.persistence(this.filename))
            .withCache("threeTieredCache",
                    CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                            Long.class, Long[].class,
                            ResourcePoolsBuilder.newResourcePoolsBuilder()
                                    .heap(10, EntryUnit.ENTRIES)
                                    .offheap(10, MemoryUnit.GB)
                                    .disk(400, MemoryUnit.GB)
                    )
            ).build(true);
        myCache = myStore.getCache("myCache", Long.class, Long[].class );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hitting the limitations of generics in Java here. You will have to stick with `List.class` in the type information you provide the cache.

This will not prevent you from declaring the cache as `Cache<Long, List<Long>>` but it will create warnings in some places and may require you to do some casts during configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I would never have figured that out by guess-and-check :D